# How to choose what components to display on a page in angular?

Tags: angular, components, frontend

I'm building an application which displays information about various tools. I want few components to remain static all through the application, example: Header, footer and one/two other components. 
What should be done for only a few components to be fetched upon routing to a URL keeping other components static/in-place? 
I'm relatively new to angular. Any info helps.

Comment: How about going through tutorials? Maybe: https://angular.io/tutorial. And also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Or as you want it to have header/footer: https://scotch.io/courses/build-your-first-angular-website/creating-an-angular-header-and-footer

Answer (score 1):

In your app.component.html you can load the static pages like this:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

where changing content will be loaded between header and footer when you will route.

Comment: it works for me.